# How does one loop audio files in Java?

Tags: java, loops, audio

This is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        // open the sound file as a Java input stream
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream("Sound.wav");

        // create an audiostream from the inputstream
        AudioStream audioStream = new AudioStream(in);

        // play the audio clip with the audioplayer class
        AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream); 
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Audio not found");
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Music Loop in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875080/music-loop-in-java)

Comment: is there a limit on how big the wav file is cause i cant seem to play my file as it keep saying file not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Sun Audio is Undocumented

You should not be using Sun Audio in your program. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21313088/5004298) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22032338/5004298).

## The Answer Depends on Your Library

If you are using Java Clip (built-in), try [the example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8980146/5004298). This is probably the simplest method.

If you switch to use JavaFX, you can see the API [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/AudioClip.html), which has ways to loop. However, JavaFX requires a bit of package restructuring, and there is a learning curve. Unless you need JavaFX for other reasons, I would avoid it.

If you are using any other library, please consult the API for that library, or share with us what you are attempting to use. I have personally used [BasicPlayer](http://www.javazoom.net/jlgui/api.html), but it is quite old.

Comment: @Kenneth If you like my answer, please upvote and mark as correct.